# Converting to float: CAST vs CONVERT vs *1.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, int

Which is preferred and why? I'm using integer values for clarity however these would be field names.

1. `SELECT 2*1.0 / 3`
2. `SELECT CAST(2 AS float) / 3`
3. `SELECT CONVERT(float, 2) / 3`

Comment: The first one doesn't convert to `float`. `1.0` is `numeric(2,1)`. You would use `SELECT 2*1E0 / 3`

Comment: @Martin Smith Thanks! Learn something every day. Ok I don't need float, just some decimal points so I can use CEILING to round up.

Comment: Depends on what your preference is exactly. Do you prefer readability, performance, maintainability, ... ?

Comment: Let's go for performance, I think it's pretty obvious what they all do when reading it.

Comment: this should answer most of it. It does not seem to have any preformance impact http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11334/cast-vs-convert-is-there-a-difference-as-far-as-sql-server-is-concerned-which-is-better.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jester, really I'm more interested in how the *1.0 solution compares with CAST/CONVERT.

Comment: Why `2 * 1.0 / 3` and not `2.0 / 3` ?

Comment: @Magnus " I'm using integer values for clarity however these would be field names"

Comment: I would definitely not go with option 1. The risk is that if someone else looks at your code they mistakenly delete the `* 1.0` as it does not immediately makes sense what is going on (as option 2 and 3 does). As for performance goes, there is probably not a measurable difference between the three.

Comment: voted to close considering I can't really pick an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a performance perspective regarding the first one and the CAST/CONVERT, I quickly created a temp table and queried it using the value of 2:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Two FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2)
SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT Two*1.0 / 3 FROM #temp
SELECT Two*1E0 / 3 FROM #temp
SELECT CAST(Two AS FLOAT) / 3 FROM #temp
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,Two) / 3 FROM #temp
```

When selecting from it, no matter how many different values I enter, the Execution plan and Statistics IO give me the same numbers (each a fourth).  I tried entering other values like 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and so on, and even more values, but the cost came as the same.  From the beyond relational article listed above this (here: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11334/cast-vs-convert-is-there-a-difference-as-far-as-sql-server-is-concerned-which-is-better.aspx), it appears that using your first method doesn't have any effect, as least on the small values (I did use 2,000,000).